# Issues Modifying Bootstrap 3 with LESS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to test modifications to BS 3 by compiling a `stylemgr.less` with

```
@import "less/bootstrap.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "nav.less";
@import "style.less";`
```

To test, I my `nav.less` looks like:

```
@navbar-default-bg: #333;'
```

My `index.html` head looks like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Title Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name=description content="">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- My CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylemgr.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I compile `stylemgr.less`, the background of the navbar does not change. Am I doing something incorrect in the code? Away from bootstrap, this kind of approach to LESS works fine (I tested it). I am just learning BS so any help / direction is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does your navbar have the class "navbar-default" ?

Comment: Have you checked a the page in Firebug? Is the CSS rule being detected?

Comment: my navbar is ==> <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

Comment: Well there's your problem then!

Comment: But in the scaffold.less file, the nav bar bg is defined by that variable. Not sure I entirely follow

Comment: I think I follow. I am recreating one from scratch and I see. Thanks for the help folks